# Integrar validate.js com dropzone.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, dropzonejs

Integrei o dropzone.js com um formulário, e precisaria validar os campos do mesmo. Tenho o seguinte código (não está funcionando, mas é o que eu preciso "juntar", no caso):

```js
var Galerias = function () {

return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    initForm: function() {

        var form = $('#my-dropzone');
        var error = $('.alert-danger', form);
        var success = $('.alert-success', form);

        form.validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            ignore: "", // validate all fields including form hidden input

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
                if (element.parent(".input-group").size() > 0) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent(".input-group"));
                } else if (element.attr("data-error-container")) { 
                    error.appendTo(element.attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.radio-list').size() > 0) { 
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-list').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.radio-inline').size() > 0) { 
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-list').size() > 0) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-list').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-inline').size() > 0) { 
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavior
                }
            },

            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                success.hide();
                error.show();
            },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
               $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            success: function (label) {
                label
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set success class to the control group
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                success.show();
                error.hide();
                $('button[type="submit"]', form).prop("disabled", true);
                $('button[type="submit"]', form).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Aguarde, enviando imagens...');
            }

        });

        //apply validation on select2 dropdown value change, this only needed for chosen dropdown integration.
        $('.select2me', form).change(function () {
            form.validate().element($(this)); //revalidate the chosen dropdown value and show error or success message for the input
        });

    },

    initDropzone: function() {

        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
            clickable: ".dropzone-previews",
            acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 500,
            maxFilesize: 5, // mb
            init: function() {

                var myDropzone = this;

                // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
                this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                });

                // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
                // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
                this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
                    // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
                    // Hide the success button or the complete form.
                    $('button[type="submit"]', form).prop("disabled", true);
                    $('button[type="submit"]', form).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Aguarde, enviando imagens...');
                });
                this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
                    // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
                    // Redirect user or notify of success.
                    alert('sucesso');
                    form[0].submit();
                });
                this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
                    // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
                    // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
                    alert('Ocorreu um erro no envio dos arquivos.');
                });
                this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                    // Create the remove button
                    var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='btn red btn-xs btn-block'>Excluir</button>");
                    
                    // Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
                    var _this = this;

                    // Listen to the click event
                    removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                      // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
                      e.preventDefault();
                      e.stopPropagation();

                      // Remove the file preview.
                      _this.removeFile(file);
                      // If you want to the delete the file on the server as well,
                      // you can do the AJAX request here.
                    });

                    // Add the button to the file preview element.
                    file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
                });

            }            
        }
        
    }
};
}();
```

```html
<form role="form" action="{$endereco}/galerias/adicionar" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="gal_id" value="{$galeria.gal_id}">
       <div class="form-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
         <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
         Você tem alguns erros no formulário. Por favor, verifique abaixo.
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
         <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
         O formulário foi validado com sucesso! Aguarde.
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3">Ativo</label>
         <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" class="make-switch" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-on-text="SIM" data-off-text="NÃO" {if $galeria.gal_active == 1 or !$livre}checked{/if}>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3">Título <span class="required"> * </span></label>
         <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Título" class="form-control required" minlength="2" maxlength="100" value="{$galeria.gal_title}">
         </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="form-section">Imagens</h3>
        <div class="dropzone-previews">
         <h4 style="margin-top: 0;">
          <i><strong>Arraste e solte ou clique aqui</strong> para enviar os arquivos</i>
          <br><small>Formatos aceitos: JPG e PNG - Tamanho máximo: 5mb - Máximo de 500 arquivos</small>
         </h4>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
          <button type="submit" class="btn green-meadow">{if !$livre}Adicionar{else}Salvar{/if}</button>
          <a href="{$endereco}/galerias/listar" class="btn default">Cancelar</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
```

O erro provavelmente está nesse trecho do código:

```
// First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
                this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                });
```

Ao submeter o formulário, primeiramente o mesmo deveria ser validado, e após ser validado iniciar o upload dos arquivos com o Dropzone.js.